# WordPress Set Automatic Media's Overwrite

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with the upload of media in wordpress. 
I use a plugin for the product's imports into the ecommerce with a csv file
The problem is when I upload an article several times, the plugin upload the image of this article several time.
Wordpress not overwrite the orginal file, but it create another file and append a number at the end of the name file.
How can I set the overwrite in wordpress? 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I cooked up which was taken mainly from the plugin [Overwrite Uploads](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/overwrite-uploads/) but without the extra stuff

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_overrides','noneUniqueFilename');
function noneUniqueFilename($overrides){
    $overrides['test_form'] = false;
    $overrides['unique_filename_callback'] = 'nonUniqueFilenameCallback';
    return $overrides;
}

function nonUniqueFilenameCallback($directory, $name, $extension){
    $filename = $name . strtolower($extension);
    //remove old attachment
    removeOldAttach($filename);

    return $filename;
}

function removeOldAttach($filename){
    $arguments = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'meta_key'      => '_wp_attached_file',
        'meta_value'    => $filename,
        'post_type'     => 'attachment'
    );
    $Attachments_to_remove = get_posts($arguments);

    foreach($Attachments_to_remove as $a)
        wp_delete_attachment($a->ID, true);
}
```

Comment: @SimoneBosio you can put this code in your active theme `functions.php`.

Comment: i tried but is not working. 
wordpress continues to create another image with a different number at the end of the file's name.

Comment: @SimoneBosio have you installed this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/overwrite-uploads/ ?